# android applying a background to the whole screen, containing more than 1 textview

Tags: android-layout

I am developing an app with a home screen, that has 6 text views, arranged in some order.
Now, I want to apply an image as a background to them.

If I apply that image to the parent layout, it's not visible as it is covered by all child layouts/textviews.So, I have to apply that background individually to all the textviews, to make it visible.

But,this is not I want.
Is there a way to apply that image as a background to the parent layout in such a way, that it is visible over all the child layouts.

Means, I want to apply that image as a background such that a single image can cover all the screen and is visible over the textviews, not applying the image to all the individual texviews.

You can also take the question as, how to make the textviews transparent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I figured out a way..
I can define a custom layout in a separate file in drawable folder.
There, I can define a selector in which I can define a shape for defining the

gradient(for background gradient
),

solid(for applying solid color)..like elements.

In the solid element, I can define the color attribute as

```
<solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
```

Then, I can apply this layout as a background to all the textviews.

OR, If you want no other effect rather than just applying the background, you can do this without creating the file.

To each TextView individually, apply the background as:

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

These both ways can solve the problem easily.